# How to fix Flutter "A RenderFlex overflowed by.." issue when keyboard opens

Tags: flutter, dart

I get a `A RenderFlex overflowed by 161 pixels on the bottom.` issue in my Flutter app when the keyboard opens and I don't know why. I'm using a `SingleChildScrollView` with a fixed height to the container. Also I tried it with `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` on Scaffold. No success.

I think that the problem has something to do with the included Pin Code Field on this page. But there I have no columns or something else... also I open this widget a ModalBottomSheet (https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet)

**Here is my code structure:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        height: Get.height,
        color: Get.theme.colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(.03),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            EntryGuestbookHeading(),
            SizedBox(height: 50),
            Obx(() {
              if (entryGuestbookController.isCheckingCode.value == true) {
                return Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      LoadingSpinner(),
                      SizedBox(height: 15),
                      Text("search_for_guestbook",
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                          .tr(),
                      SizedBox(height: 50),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            }),
            PinCodeField(
              guestbookCodeController: guestbookCodeController,
            ),
            EntryGuestbookActions(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
```

**EntryGuestbookHeading Widget**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: context.isTablet
          ? EdgeInsets.only(left: 150, right: 150, top: 100)
          : null,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Lottie.asset("assets/animations/key.json",
              height: Get.height / 8, repeat: false),
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          Container(
            child: Text(
              "open_guestbook",
              style: Get.theme.textTheme.headline3,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            ).tr(),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          Text(
            tr("enter_entry_code"),
            style: Get.theme.textTheme.bodyText1,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**PinCodeField Widget**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Container(
          padding: context.isTablet
              ? EdgeInsets.only(left: 150, right: 150, bottom: 150)
              : null,
          child: PinCodeTextField(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            appContext: context,
            length: 5,
            focusNode: focusNode,
            autoDisposeControllers: false,
            obsecureText: false,
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
            animationType: AnimationType.slide,
            autoFocus: true,
            enableActiveFill: true,
            pinTheme: PinTheme(
              shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              fieldHeight: 50,
              fieldWidth: 40,
              inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
              inactiveFillColor: Colors.transparent,
              selectedColor: Get.theme.colorScheme.primary,
              selectedFillColor: Get.theme.colorScheme.primary,
              activeColor: Get.theme.colorScheme.primary,
              activeFillColor: Get.theme.colorScheme.primary,
            ),
            animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            controller: widget.guestbookCodeController,
            onCompleted: (v) {
              entryGuestbookController.checkEntryCode(v).then((success) {
                if (success == false) {
                  setState(() {
                    guestbookCodeController.text = "";
                  });
                  focusNode.requestFocus();
                }
              });
            },
            onChanged: (value) => null,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**EntryGuestbookActions Widget**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
        child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50),
            child: FlatButton(
                child: Text("cancel",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Get.theme.colorScheme.onBackground))
                    .tr(),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                })));
  }
```

The `autofocus` is set to true. If the keyboard opens, I get the overflow error. Where is the issue in my code? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you got any workaround for it?

Answer (score 4):

```
Scaffold(
resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false, )
```

Comment: Please read my topic. I've tried this already. It does not work. Btw: `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding ` is deprecated. We should use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset ` instead. Source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomPadding.html

Answer (score 1):

I think now the flutter has updated its properties, and using

```
Scaffold (
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,)
```

would work as we expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the widget that causes this error with Flexible or Expanded widget. This may solve your problem.

Comment: Flexible does not solve the multithreading/Future problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I was working on a Signup page and this problem occurred. I just wrapped the first container with a singleChildScrollView, and then wrapped it to the Center Widget, and it worked.